# EEVEE Adding noise texture lags out renderer

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, performance

I'm trying to make a Dr. Strange style shield, I've got the lighting down, but whenever I add the noise texture to vary the light on the shield, it lags out whenever I try to render the animation. Any ideas on how to stop this? My hardware is probably overpowered for this so its quite confusing.

([Blend file attached](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kXruErlhKMpxfGXmwNTX0u8qiNWzx1Pz/view?usp=sharing))

Comment: Possibly the same issue as https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/200952/29586