# Eevee way much slower than Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I've got a scene where Eevee viewport is so much slower that even makes my whole computer impossible to work with but when I change to Cycles it gets smooth like butter again.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you[image]

Comment: A screenshot with default Eeevee settings is not really signifiant.. how is your scene?

Comment: My Scene has 6 characters exported from Daz3D as .obj
Some has hair, other doesn't just to make the scene a bit lighter. 
And around 90 rocks not Instanced (will need to instance soon to get all work more smoothly).
it's..9,000,000 faces right now. I'm a noob with blender and didn't care about it till it started getting slow. 
But my point is that, I thought eevee was quicker than cycles.
And now, while I can continue working with cycles, when I switch to Eevee it's impossible to even move the camera around.

Comment: Daz if often very high poly... that can be that (it depends on the concrete models you've imported).

Comment: Is it normal that eevee gets slower than cycles just because there are too many polys?

Comment: I have the same scene without the rocks, which is 3M faces only with the characters and it still too laggy to work with Eevee viewport. There must be something causing this.

Comment: I think it's more than likely your materials rather than your scene itself. I have had issues where using multiple Noise textures and other texture nodes within a material can really hurt performance on Eevee (I presume it pre-renders some surfaces to optimise the actual render - and this seems to cause a performance hit whenever the scene or materials are changed). Try removing your materials one at a time and see which (if any) is causing the lag.

Comment: This one makes much more sense to me. I've tried to slowly not removing but hiding the Eye on each materials. And I can see some makes it slower in just a second but once it starts to get slow ,even if I hide that texture again it's hard to get it back to smooth again and to try to find another texture that is could be ALSO responsible for the lag.

Answer (score 7):

It’s likely that it’s your materials rather than your scene itself that’s causing the lag.

I have had issues in the past where using multiple Noise textures and other texture nodes within a material can really hurt performance on Eevee. This seems to be due to Eevee pre-rendering some surface textures to optimise the actual render - and this seems to cause a performance hit whenever the scene or materials are changed. Try removing your materials one at a time and see which (if any) is causing the lag. You may be able to simplify any materials that are proven to be causing the issue.

---

Update: I've recently made some more progress on this and tracked down slow Eevee performance to multi-dimensional Texture nodes in particular. For example, using a 3D texture (such as the default for Noise) where perhaps a 2D texture (Noise set to '2D') would do - for example, when using a UV map, the Noise (or other texture) should be set to '2D' to drastically improve performance.

Note that Eevee appears to pre-sample such textures and so reducing the Dimensions to the bare minimum for that case will *drastically* reduce the overhead (eg, it only needs to pre-sample a plane for a 2D texture instead of a volume for a 3D texture - the extra dimension is wasted processing time if that dimension is never actually going to be used).

Note that in extreme cases I have had Blender crash due to this - when I swapped from Cycles render view (which worked fine) to Material Preview mode (which uses Eevee regardless of your render settings). Reducing the dimensions often resolves the crash - as well as making the interface much more responsive.

Comment: What can I say? You are a 7uckng genius and lifesaver!